# How do I keep command options from breaking other scripts executed within my command?

Tags: shell-script, parameter, readlink

I have a bash shell script(`my_script.sh`) which runs a script(`their_script`) during execution. My script (`my_script.sh`) looks like this :

```
THISDIR=`dirname $(readlink -f $0)`
main() {
    cd $THISDIR
    source their-script
}
main "$@"
```

`their-script` is a file I should not change.  `their-script` has this stuff:

```
BDIR="$1"
...
BDIR=`readlink -f "$BDIR"
```

Everything above works great.  I would like to add some options, so I changed `my_script.sh` to look like this:

```
THISDIR=`dirname $(readlink -f $0)`
check_options() {
    while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
        case $1 in
            --username )  shift
                          OPTIONS_USERNAME=$1
                          ;;
            * )           # No more options
                          ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}

main() {
    check_options
    cd $THISDIR
    source their-script
}
main "$@"
```

Now, when I run `./my_script.sh --username example`, `their-script` fails during execution of:

```
readlink -f --username
```

and spits out this line:

```
readlink: unrecognized option '--username'
```

How can I prevent my script's positional parameters from breaking other scripts in this way?

Comment: what exactly do you want to pass to `readlink`?

Comment: For a start you should quote all your variables.  [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @roaima pointed out, you likely want to run the script in a separate process. Sourcing it in your code without full understanding of it's internal workings can be rather dangerous:

```
FILE_TO_REMOVE="/tmp/foobar"
source some-cool-script
rm -Rf "$FILE_TO_REMOVE"
```

is rather obviously not the right way to go about things , because the cool script may so happen to include

```
FILE_TO_REMOVE=/
```

Not to mention that the script might be changed at any time (even if it is not "actively" maintained).

Apart from that, there are several things you should consider:

1. processing positional parameters is better controlled by the number of parameters left:

   ```
   while [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
   ...
   done
   ```

   empty string like `""` may be a perfectly valid argument, unless you want to use it as a separator. Even if you do (traditionally `--` is used), it is arguably better to keep the above condition and use:

   ```
       case "$1" in
           ...
           "")
               shift
               break
               ;;
           ...
       esac
   ```

   which is easier to maintain.
2. The `$@` variable is per scope. That means that if you decide to execute the external script as it is usually done, i.e. by calling it instead of sourcing it in your code, you'll need to pass it the arguments:

   ```
   their-script "$@"
   ```

   Using a full path to the script might not be a bad idea either, especially if the script is being run with elevated privileges.
3. The above also means, that this actually doesn't check command line arguments:

   ```
   main() {
       check_options
   }
   main "$@"
   ```

   You need to call it as

   ```
       check_options "$@"
   ```
4. The above however also means that arguments in `main` will not be modified in any way by `check_options`. If you need to filter some options so that they don't end up crashing the external script (and given your question you do) it leaves you with two options:

   - put the option parsing into `main` or even into the global scope of your script. It's faster and a bit messy as far as code cleanliness is considered.
   - keep option parsing in a separate function and do some variable juggling:

     ```
     check_options {
         # parse options magic
         # what needs to be passed over is
         # kept in a separate variable
         PASS_THROUGH_OPTS=...
     }

     main {
         check_options "$@"
         set -- $PASS_THROUGH_OPTS
         ...
     }
     ```

     Note that this doesn't handle the possibility that positional parameters may contain spaces or other word separators. I don;t know of any other way to handle this properly than by using arrays (which is implementation specific) and involves things like:

     ```
     check_options {
         ...
             # parameter should be kept for further use
             x=( "${x[@]}" "$1" )
         ...
     }

     check_options "$@"
     set -- "${x[@]}"
     ```

Answer (score 3):

The `source their-script` command tells your shell to execute `their-script` directly in the context of your script. This means it has access to all your variables, and can even change them.

If you remove the word `source` and just run `their-script` as a command it will be unable to affect any of your code, and its `$1` will be the first argument you give it, so in this example its `$1` will take the value `banana`:

```
their-script banana
```